# How to return a specific class

Tags: java

So I have a game class

```
public class Game {

public Game(int id){
    this.gameId = id;
    Waiting(); //TODO - Change place
} }
```

Usage: `Game game1 = new Game(1);`

And I'm trying to make a game manager that return a specific Game class.

Example: `getGame(1);`

So I tried this:

```
    public Game getGame(int id){
      Game game = getGame(id);
      return game;
    }
```

And I realize it woun't work because I'm creating an instance of Game with an id and I want to get an existing instance of Game. I don't have a single clue on how I could solve this problem.

Comment: You could e.g. use a `HashMap<Integer, Game>` in your game manager class. If someone requests a game with an existing ID return it from the map, otherwise create a new game for the new ID, put it into the map and return it afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common solution: Singleton Design Pattern with a `Map` holding all instances:

```
class Game {
    private static final HashMap<Integer , Game> games = new HashMap<>();

    public static Game getGame(int i){
         if(games.get(i) == null)
             games.put(i , new Game(i));

         return games.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really avoid singletons if possible. If anything, you should instead pass an instance of a `GameManager` which contains the map, then access the games through the `GameManager`. Or better yet, encapsulate the creation and access of games within the `GameManager`, so the games dont need to know of their container. No need for global access

Comment: Whenever I create an instance of Game should I do this: games.put(id, this);

Comment: This is not a Singleton. In reality, this is just some bookkeeping, since you will simply create some new object, if `games.get(i)` returns `null`. You are basically creating the Java-version of a memory leak because (unless the user explicitly deletes the map entries) each and every game you create never gets garbage collected.

Comment: i know it's a memory-leak. nevertheless it's what op asked for.

Comment: He didn't ask for a memory leak.. You should never pass anyone potentially dangerous code without warning. @Turing85 Correct. I was just letting him know singletons should only be used in certain context. My main point was avoid global state if possible. Guess I should have rephrased that

Comment: @VinceEmigh well, i guess since theres no other answer, this is the answer to ops question (though it's not a nice solution)

Comment: Touche ;) I'm on my phone, would rather not type up an answer right now. I just really hope you don't use these techniques in your own code! Please fix the leak, to make sure anyone in the future doesn't become a victim to it. If `games.get(i)` is null, don't create a new game. Either return `null`, return a [Null Object](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), or throw an exception.

Comment: well, it's up to op how exactly he wants to store/generate the `Game` instances. I just intended to give an example for how to store the instances in the required way. i personally would prefer a non-static solution aswell, but with this little code...

Comment: @Paul *well, i guess since theres no other answer, this is the answer to ops question (though it's not a nice solution)*. That is not how stackoverflow works. You should take a look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Accepting an answer "just because it is the only one" is a very, very bad practice.